# Merge two lists and write to a text file in CONLL data format

Tags: python, merge

I have two lists as shown below:

```
pos_tag(word_tokenize('This shoe is of Blue color.'))

[('This', 'DT'),
 ('shoe', 'NN'),
 ('is', 'BEZ'),
 ('of', 'IN'),
 ('Blue', 'JJ-TL'),
 ('color', 'NN'),
 ('.', '.')]

custom_tags('This shoe is of Blue color.')
Out[125]: 
[('This', 'Other'),
 ('shoe', 'Product'),
 ('is', 'Other'),
 ('of', 'Other'),
 ('Blue', 'Color'),
 ('color', 'Other'),
 ('.', 'Other')]
```

which are returned by two functions.
Now I want to merge them into one and finally write into a text file in the format of CONLL as shown below:

```
LEICESTERSHIRE NNP I-NP I-ORG
TAKE NNP I-NP O
OVER IN I-PP O
AT NNP I-NP O
TOP NNP I-NP O
AFTER NNP I-NP O
INNINGS NNP I-NP O
VICTORY NN I-NP O
```

Only in my case the output will be:

```
This    DT  Other
shoe    NN  Product
is  BEZ Other
of  IN  Other
Blue    JJ-TL   Color
Color   NN  Other
```

I have tried to do this using:

```
list(zip(pos_tag(word_tokenize(sentence)),custom_tags(sentence)))
```

But this gives me :

```
[(('This', 'DT'), ('This', 'Other')),
 (('footwear', 'NN'), ('footwear', 'Product')),
 (('is', 'BEZ'), ('is', 'Other')),
 (('of', 'IN'), ('of', 'Other')),
 (('blue', 'JJ'), ('blue', 'Color')),
 (('color', 'NN-HL'), ('color', 'Other'))]
```

Can someone please help me in getting the desired output and I also need to write each output into a text file with some separator between the lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a comprehension

```
l1=[('This', 'DT'), ('shoe', 'NN'), ('is', 'BEZ'), ('of', 'IN'), ('Blue', 'JJ-TL'), ('color', 'NN'), ('.', '.')]
l2=[('This', 'Other'), ('shoe', 'Product'), ('is', 'Other'), ('of', 'Other'), ('Blue', 'Color'), ('color', 'Other'), ('.', 'Other')]

l3=[(x[0][0],x[0][1],x[1][1]) for x in zip(l1, l2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to use append, even though it is not the most elegant way ?

```
    A =

    [('This', 'DT'),
     ('shoe', 'NN'),
     ('is', 'BEZ'),
     ('of', 'IN'),
     ('Blue', 'JJ-TL'),
     ('color', 'NN'),
     ('.', '.')]

    B =
    [('This', 'Other'),
     ('shoe', 'Product'),
     ('is', 'Other'),
     ('of', 'Other'),
     ('Blue', 'Color'),
     ('color', 'Other'),
     ('.', 'Other')]

    Title = 
    [('This', ),
     ('shoe', ),
     ('is', ),
     ('of', ),
     ('Blue', ),
     ('color', ),
     ('.', )]

    for j, item in enumerate(A):
        Title[j].append(item)
        Title[j].append(B[j][1])

    for tuple in Title:
        line = '{0[0]} {0[1]} {0[2]}'.format(tuple)
```

For write files use open()
For example,

```
    f = open('This/is/your/destination/file.txt', 'w')
    # Here you do something

    f.write( )
    f.close()
```